# String splitting in C

Tags: c

I am trying to improve my C skills, and I hope someone might be able to provide me with some feedback on the following code.

It is just basic string splitting, it should behave the similar to [Ruby's String#split](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) or Clojure's clojure.string.split. I couldn't think of a simple/efficient way to create an array of variable-size strings so I went the callback route.

Anyway, any and all feedback is greatly appreciated, thank you! Check out the code:

```
void strsplit(char *str, char *delim, int limit, void (*cb)(char *s, int idx))
{
  char *search = strdup(str);

  if (limit == 1) {
    cb(search, 0);
  }
  else {
    int i = 0, count = 0, len = strlen(str), len_delim = strlen(delim);
    char *segment = NULL, *leftover = NULL;
    limit = limit > 0 ? limit - 1 : len;

    segment = strtok(search, delim);
    for (i = 0; segment != NULL && i < limit; i++) {
      count += strlen(segment) + len_delim;
      cb(segment, i);
      segment = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }

    if (len != limit && count < len) {
      leftover = (char*) malloc(len - count + 1);
      memcpy(leftover, str + count, len - count);
      leftover[len - count] = '\0';
      cb(leftover, i);
      free(leftover);
    }
  }
}
```

Also see the [code with a test framework](http://ideone.com/5dXY1).

Comment: Hmm...at least for me, `strdup` doesn't lead to warm fuzzy feelings, and `strtok` makes me feel...less than happy.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Can you point me to some literature as to why I should avoid these guys?

Comment: `strdup` should be avoided because it's non-standard (though, in fairness, it is pretty widely available). `strtok` should be avoided because it's ugly to use, requires heroic efforts to be thread safe, and can't be used on string literals. Duplicating the input avoids the last problem, but not the other two.

Comment: I might be missing the call here, but you need to be sure to call `free` on your `search` string since you called `strdup` to allocate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a few comments. You need a comment giving a better definition of what the function should do.  Otherwise we have to guess what your approximation to the Ruby function might be.  An alternative interface might be to pass in a pointer array and its length instead of the callback.

- I prefer to use `strspn` and `strcspn` or `strsep` if available to locate the tokens (just my preference).
- `str` and `delim` should be const char *
- I'd prefer to see the `limit == 1` case handled in the main clause.  Is there
  a good reason to treat it separately?
- Each variable on its own line
- I think you can modify the algorithm to avoid having to count the length of
  the string (`strlen(str)`).   I don't think either `len` or `count` is necessary.
- efficiency: you traverse the string with `strlen` at the start, then `strtok` traverses each word and then you do it again with `strlen` on the word.
- why limit - 1 ??
- not sure `count` will be computed correctly (`len_delim` added but
  the actual sequence of separators present may not be of that length)
- prefer `len < limit` to `len != limit` (more robust to future changes)
- is the condition for the final `if` clause correct?  When do you want it to be
  executed?
- prefer brackets round multiple conditions `((len != limit) && (count < len))`
- why use both `strdup` and `malloc` ?
- malloc return should not be cast (C not C++)
- why malloc the remaining string from `str` instead of just modifying `search` - it is
  already writeable because you strdup-ed it
- the duped string should be freed on return, else it is a leak.  Depends
  what the callback does with the bits of course.

Possibly missed other things - but there are enough things above to be going on with I guess :-)

Comment: Awesome, thank you, this is exactly the critical feedback I was hoping for.

Comment: The reason for `limit == 1` is to handle the case that no splitting is required, this mimics the behaviour of the Ruby and Clojure behaviour.

Comment: I then use `limit - 1` to match zero-based iteration with the limit.

Comment: I believe I require `len` and `count` to track the offset of the last match, so I can then return the rest of the unsplit string in case of a limit.

Comment: I incorrectly assumed that `strdup` allocated on the stack, so I did not free it. How embarrassing.

Comment: I'm not sure about your comments here - without an exact definition of what the code should do it is impossible to determine.  Note that the code in your test framework fails if you change the `delim` strings from `;` to something like `;:`.  I think this would be a valid delimiter string according to your definition of the problem but maybe I misunderstood. It is good to do examples, but for my money, to be worth doing, a full definition of the requirement should precede the design (and review) of the code :-)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest not rolling your own implementation; just use `strtok_r` properly and save yourself some time. For memory allocation, you can either use the offsets into the string in-place, or use `strndup` to get copies of each token as you find it.

Comment: This is purely for learning experience. It isn't actually being used anywhere.